# Regular expression convert url to hyperlink

Tags: c#, .net, regex, bbcode

I've googled some code that converts an url into a hyperlink using bbcode The code is :

```
// format the url tags: [url=www.website.com]my site[/url]
// becomes: <a href="www.website.com">my site</a>
exp = new Regex(@"\[url\=([^\]]+)\]([^\]]+)\[/url\]");
str = exp.Replace(str, "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>");

// format the img tags: [img]www.website.com/img/image.jpeg[/img]
// becomes: <img src="www.website.com/img/image.jpeg" />
exp = new Regex(@"\[img\]([^\]]+)\[/img\]");
str = exp.Replace(str, "$1\" />");
```

I also want to convert ordinary links hyperlinks.I've googled some more and got this:

```
exp = new Regex("(http://[^ ]+)");
str = exp.Replace(str, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```

The problem is, when i mix them and third regular expression is executed, the first two will be messed up. as it could result in :

```
<img src="<a href='www.website.com/img/image.jpeg>www.website.com/img/image.jpeg</a>" />
```

how can i specify in my third regular expression that he cannot convert strings that begin with 'href="' or 'src="' ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract the url+parameters out of a bbcode url tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257607/how-to-extract-the-urlparameters-out-of-a-bbcode-url-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the interesting combinations of tags users could throw at you, regular expressions quickly become cumbersome and difficult to use for parsing tags.

BBCode is essentially a grammar unto itself, and the best way to interpret a grammar programmatically is with an actual parser.

Have a look at http://bbcode.codeplex.com/. I can't vouch for its effectiveness, but they've implemented a parser for BBCode in C# that might do what you're looking for.

Comment: basic regular expressions also don't have enough business logic in them to be able to protect you against sly users. It's very easy for a user to do something like [url]javascript:window.alert("lolol")[/url], or [img] http://path.to/a/script.php [/img], and cause all manner of havoc.